# Sed conversion with captures

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to convert this string:

```
{{# sender_phone }}
```

to this one:

```
<% if sender_phone do %>
```

I've started with a simple `sed` and trying to grew it. This works fine:

```
$ echo '{{# sender_phone }}' | sed -e 's|{{# \(sender_phone\) }}|<% \1 %>|g'
<% sender_phone %>
$
```

This works fine too:

```
$ echo '{{# sender_phone }}' | sed -e 's|{{# \(.*\) }}|<% \1 %>|g'
<% sender_phone %>
$
```

However, sometimes the input string in question may contain additional `}}`. In this case my regex is too greedy:

```
$ echo '{{# sender_phone }} {{ something else }}' | sed -e 's|{{# \(.*\) }}|<% \1 %>|g'
<% sender_phone }} {{ something else %>
$
```

Trying to make it less greedy (note a `?` symbol) I am hitting a wall – nothing matches:

```
$ echo '{{# sender_phone }} {{ something else }}' | sed -e 's|{{# \(.*?\) }}|<% \1 %>|g'
{{# sender_phone }} {{ something else }}
$
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I usually just do `[^ ]*`

Comment: Restoring original tags added by OP to highlight nature of question i.e. `regex` in `sed`. Only tag that may be redundant here is `bash` but both `sed` and `regex` are pertinent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple simple changes to the OP's current `sed` call:

```
# current
echo '{{# sender_phone }} {{ something else }}' | sed -e 's|{{# \(.*\) }}|<% \1 %>|g'
<% sender_phone }} {{ something else %>

# new/proposed
echo '{{# sender_phone }} {{ something else }}' | sed -e 's|{{# \(.*\) }}[^}]|<% \1 %> |g'
<% sender_phone %> {{ something else }}
```

The key is to limit the match to the first `}}` it finds by adding `[^}]`  which, in essence, says to continue matching up to the next `}`.

By itself this change will generate the desired output sans the (space) between the `<...>` and `{{..}}` strings, so I've also added an extra (space) at the end of the replacement pattern `<% \1 %>`.

**NOTE**: If you know the double curly braces come in pairs, ie, there is always a `{{` prior to a `}}`, then you could also use `[^{]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `sed`, but here's a regex that's working in a Perl one-liner:

```
$ cat temp.txt 
{{# sender_phone }}
{{# sender_phone }} {{ something else }}

$ perl -pe 's/\{\{#\s*sender_phone\s*\}\}/<% if sender_phone do %>/' temp.txt 
<% if sender_phone do %>
<% if sender_phone do %> {{ something else }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is greedy and `sed` doesn't have a lazy quantifier.

However, you may use this `sed`:

```
s='{{# sender_phone }} {{ something else }}'
sed -E 's/{{# *([_[:alnum:]]+) *}}/<% if \1 do %>/g' <<< "$s"
```

```
<% if sender_phone do %> {{ something else }}
```

`[_[:alnum:]]` will match `_` or an alphanumerical character